# mapping sql to python

Tags: python, sql, dsl

I'm trying to express SQL queries as python code, but I have trouble expressing the limit function

I represent an SQL table in python as

```
[{'col1':val, 'col2':val,...},...]
```

The following SQL expression

```
SELECT x.val, y.val
FROM R x, S y
WHERE x.id = y.id
```

would then in python be expressed as

```
for x in R:
   for y in S:
      if x["id"] == y["id"]:
         x["val"], y["val"]
```

If I wanted to limit the output to 10 rows I could then write

```
i = 0
for x in R:
   for y in S:
      if x["id"] == y["id"]:
         x["val"], y["val"]
         i += 1
         if i == 10:
             break
   if i == 10:
       break
```

My way of expressing the limit function in python is cumbersome and not very elegant, so I was hoping that someone could help expressing this in a more elegant way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd use iteration, list comprehensions or generators and the [`itertools` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html):

```
from itertools import product, islice

# all values, generator expression
query = ((x['val'], y['val']) for x, y in product(R, S) if x['id'] == y['id'])

# just the first 10
limited = islice(query, 10)

for row in limited:
    print row
```